# URL rewrite without redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two urls

> domain.com / domain.de

that redirect to

> domain.other-host.de

Is it possible via url-rewriting that the user won't see

> domain.other-host.de

in his browser but

> domain.com

Thanks in advance,

Tobi

Comment: you mean user enters `domain.com`  and it shows content for `domain.other-host.de`?? If not, Please edit your question and explain better!

Comment: Yes that is what i meant. We want to dismiss a server and while the domains are transferred to us, the domains are redirecting to a placeholder. But we want that the original domains are visible for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `P` flag of mod_rewrite which hands the URI over to mod_proxy.

In the htaccess file for the domain.com and domain.de document roots, add something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.other-host.de/$1 [L,P]
```

If mod_proxy isn't enabled, this isn't going to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible* with rewriting. You can accomplish this effect using reverse-proxying, though. See the mod_proxy Apache documentation. Note that this will cause each request will pass through both domains, doubling your bandwidth usage and slowing things down for the user.

*Adding the [P] flag to a RewriteRule will cause the rule to be processed by proxying, but mod_proxy must be installed and enabled first. The above caveats still apply with this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not a big expert on this but to my knowledge, this has to be done in the server. That's how I remember it being done the last time I looked in the bowls of an **IIS**. And [this thread](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?128217-changing-the-url-in-address-bar) confirms it.

Like they suggest, you can also **pop up a window** with no address bar or **use frames** but both these methods will be highly annoying.